# Reading in a number.txt file and finding averages

Tags: java, file-io, average, parseint

currently working on an assignment and I need to read in a file of numbers and display the total amount of numbers, total even numbers, total odd numbers, and the averages of all three. I am currently struggling to find the average of the even numbers and the odd numbers. I have to display the average of the even number and the average of the odd numbers.  I found the total average by using parseInt to convert the string of numbers i read in to ints so i could calculate the average but when i tried to do the same for even and odd numbers i couldnt get it to work

here is my current code:

```
public class Homework1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  // reads file in
  File num = new File("numbers.txt");
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(num);
  // creates rounding object
  DecimalFormat rounding = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
  // neccesary variables
  int count = 0;
  double numbers =0;
  int evenNum =0;
  int oddNum =0;
  double avg;
  double evenAvg;
  double oddAvg;
  double sum = 0.0;
  double evenSum = 0.0;
  double oddSum = 0.0;

  // reads in numbers file until last line is read
  while(inputFile.hasNext())
  {
         String nums = inputFile.nextLine();
  // converts string to ints so numbers can be added
         sum += Integer.parseInt(nums);
  // converts string to ints to so odd/even nums can be distinguished
         numbers = Integer.parseInt(nums);
  // updates total number count
         count++;

  // separates evens from odds
  if(numbers % 2 == 0)
      {
         evenNum++;
         evenSum += Integer.parseInt(nums);
      }

      else
         oddNum++;
         evenSum += Integer.parseInt(nums);
   } 

   // calculates total num average
   avg = sum/count; 

  // evenAvg = 
 //  oddAvg =  

   // output of credentials and results

   System.out.println("There are " +count+ " numbers in the file"+"\n");
   System.out.println("There are " +evenNum+ " even numbers"+"\n");
   System.out.println("There are " +oddNum+ " odd numbers"+"\n");
   System.out.println("The total average value is " +rounding.format(avg)+"\n"); 
   System.out.println("The odd number average is " +rounding.format(evenAvg)+"\n");
   System.out.println("The even number average is " +rounding.format(oddAvg)+"\n");

}
```

Output:

```
There are 982 numbers in the file

There are 474 even numbers

There are 508 odd numbers

The total average value is 50362.43
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: add some brackets around `else
         oddNum++;
         evenSum += Integer.parseInt(nums);`

Comment: Your `else` block should have braces to enclose the two statements. Also, you're incrementing the sum of even numbers in the block of odd ones.

Comment: wow alright yeah thanks guys looks like it was just those two technical issues prevented me from getting the results I needed thanks for all your help @ernest_k

Comment: just saw that as well thanks you very much @ScaryWombat

Comment: uncomment `evenAvg = oddSum/oddNum;
  oddAvg =  evenSum/evenNum;` then should output expected results.

Answer (score 1):

okay so I corrected the if/else statements and added the brackets and this fixed the problem i was having

```
oddNum++;
         oddSum += Integer.parseInt(nums);
```